# Obtaining a single line from a variable result in Python

Tags: python

I am a self-learner in Python and i'm right now exploring web-scraping and things like that.
I have been working with Tumblr pictures, they work oddly, since they have several links in the same sentence, but I have been able to get one link per line, but I just want to get one link.

I guessed this would returned me something like:

```
source (blog_name)
link (the link which ends with 400w)
```

But no, I won't get any results from this.
If I take off the `if` statement, I would get something like this:

```
source (blog_name)
link (75w)
link (100w)
link (250w)
link (400w)
link (400w)
```

Here is the code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


posts_scrape = requests.get('tumblr.com/search/thingtosearch')
soup = BeautifulSoup(posts_scrape.text, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='_2DpMA')



def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text



for article in articles:
    
    try:
        post_notes = article.find('span', class_='_22VV4').text
        
        if 'notes' in post_notes:
            source = article.find('div', class_='_3QBiZ').text
                     
                for imgvar in article.find_all('img', alt='Image'):
                    
                    url_results = imgvar['srcset']

                    r_urls = url_results.replace(',','\n')
                    for line in r_urls:
                        if line.find("400w"):
                            print(source)
                            print(r_urls)
                            break
   
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the avatar image link..? If yes, why would you use `alt='Image'` whereas tumblr uses `alt='Avatar'` ..?

Comment: I am not, I want to get one link from every post but I get a lot of link from every post based on pixels

Comment: Okay, got it now... So, You want all three pictures for a post with witdth `400w`

Comment: That's it, yes, sorry if I didnt explain myself correctly the first time

Comment: first you should clean your code - you have wrong indentations. And if you don't use `getdata()` then remove it form code.

Comment: @victorsionado you are unnecessarily using the `getdata()` function as mentioned by @furas

Comment: first you chould use `print()` to see what you have in variables - your `r_urls` is string and using `for line in r_urls` you get char by char. You would have to split it `r_urls.split('\n')` or maybe `r_urls.split(',')` to work line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, You have kind of messed up your code and it uses a lot many `for loops` than required.

The reason your code doesn't work as expected is cause you are using the `if` conditional to check `line.find('400w')` which will either return an index or `-1` no matter which index it returns other than `index 0` the `if` conditional is always going to evalueate to `True`.

And secondly your `line` and `r_urls` variables are strings which contain all urls and one of those urls is always going to end in `400w` so it will always evaluate to `True` as it can never be at the index `0` and as it is a string when you output `print(r_urls)` it will print urls altogether as these were in the same string.

The following is somewhat cleaner way to do what you want:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_term = 'dog'
posts_scrape = requests.get('https://www.tumblr.com/search/search_term')
soup = BeautifulSoup(posts_scrape.text, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='_2DpMA')

for article in articles:
    try:
        source = article.find('div', class_='_3QBiZ').text
        urls = []
        for imgvar_avatar in article.find_all('img', alt='Image'):
            url_list = [i for i in imgvar_avatar['srcset'].split(',') if (i.find('400w') != -1)]
            urls.extend(url_list)
        print(f'{source} : {urls}')
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

This outputs in the following format:
`blog name: [list of links for all the 'Images' in it with width 400w]`
Sample output for `search_term = 'dog'`:

```py
everythingfox : []
liriusworldfaws : []
cuteness--overload : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/bdbfcdf3fc0462eb3be656f0c8085792/e47c10ace1710c69-dc/s400x600/41420a481f8150b866eab574e56cc43e6d8181ef.jpg 400w']
everythingfox : []
delta-breezes : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/6ed0b95f72eb90a88dd15cb546d913c8/1a24f512409f7700-c6/s400x600/456a6e3ac2f073fba90dbe885c5868063f3a1f39.jpg 400w']
fluffygif : []
scampthecorgi : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/05c8f0b3345906fc7e6c04282cee9382/4b68a8516b31bce5-6c/s400x600/bd689d26dcb0d39e1c9c2aec494247da425f5f25.jpg 400w']
sirartwork : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/7329e508e44714f33f90bd69a26fb08e/d998f5e61b3dfe95-b5/s400x600/1c40fbb26161cfac31e9fe72c89bc4305dc9820e.jpg 400w']
k-ayo : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/36580aa2e20ce45761d4d76f0c9a502d/044c64a380aaef8e-74/s400x600/bdaa0c14a96c8d4bf5cd61620e0d7384a1c13b05.jpg 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/a42440c97a294c4f53b8a0747d5a009e/044c64a380aaef8e-b3/s400x600/d49ff2b41c44846e002ed96d45e1adfcd59b2753.jpg 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/44f559aaf1babb250e650cfc3fa94070/044c64a380aaef8e-95/s400x600/abf3c7e3e6ba0de41258a1e7424d961dcb19616b.jpg 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/44a2c5351564ab917e114672daa737ab/044c64a380aaef8e-8e/s400x600/181e0316dce57706532cbf1becc3509725fc7683.jpg 400w']
pugsandfrenchbulldogs : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/c09c92db68fd0beee2ede0cffff896c2/658837adc5e2db43-7f/s400x600/ffe111d3133966be7c05507a6f75cf08d10afc59.jpg 400w']
cuteness--overload : []
everythingfox : []
fascinic : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/55cebf41bb3c979fdc68d4c09e32d96c/9a6d6375418d7a14-0b/s400x600/5df22c0d01f39932b883585fcafc80944dd489c5.jpg 400w']
cuteness--overload : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/dc6b9d9955244eefc8e6de0690f970d3/e6517da006b766fc-6a/s400x600/9a0a24db65fb8265e2b42d049f58ca376997743d.jpg 400w']
cuteness--overload : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/2fcf4bfdf94bc7725fc1064cc5fb37bb/4a5db62ba4bbd86e-12/s400x600/61a9826f9eff0c2de1984c7f5fe0ef535560eece.jpg 400w']
catasters : []
male--wife : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/b849ab48e135972b5a0566491bdcea93/1f844f181a482794-a1/s400x600/cc6605131bd901a0246e61448f7a9caca8112be9.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/97ec5949947d8aed0cec995c0a74e3c3/1f844f181a482794-65/s400x600/cc58a0efcbc621f7033e71166d310779faa2b400.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/099b77b5f560330b48757febabdfb314/1f844f181a482794-45/s400x600/1370ae9dc74d2f6e30a376703a8a0d09277cc5a8.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/322b69a71f34171cc05906b446b2615a/1f844f181a482794-49/s400x600/549108985e37b0c823be0b7438e1c7de834a9b2e.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/bfb082cdd44c2545e58424ec704cdb2c/1f844f181a482794-1b/s400x600/d5f1ba9af3aa3e930e329ac230980b73f6882faa.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/a210dbea09d5bfbb60c0d01b3d07825d/1f844f181a482794-c1/s400x600/b9d380228956b7493415b08fac6f2f7e22a1e484.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/2d904ff086e5fee6282aaa02d99f7045/1f844f181a482794-78/s400x600/82d26a959fa1f79072673c5a3a7ff52df93d574d.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/c478911a2ea835549fc3c94018086233/1f844f181a482794-46/s400x600/f307f706a186febd4c02723de297dbcd3524f1a4.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/2e091b16060114ab6a501556f1992be2/1f844f181a482794-71/s400x600/45ace560d7ef390d041fa4883c64a656280ebd66.png 400w', ' https://64.media.tumblr.com/6bf67260c9286b800af99c7d15ccfa42/1f844f181a482794-0d/s400x600/b5496b038d4c27824df53df6fa00e183d6fa9bd3.png 400w']
liriusworldfaws : []
puppy-esso : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/825ca92b45b1810f9182ca9631bf1560/7ebd600d44780133-1f/s400x600/14ea5af4c9e149cb88863dfc0117f10a62c82e99.jpg 400w']
hitmewithcute : [' https://64.media.tumblr.com/db5993448e5d8bb8228e0f1b81142e7a/dcefa14e006d548b-77/s400x600/f4d1dadd5b6a49417c8d15573972775e9e707a53.jpg 400w']
```

Comment: I see in my output too there are a few empty lists most probably for articles without `img` tags with `Image` as `alt` attribute. But the rest of the output seems to be what you were asking for.Let  me know me this is the output you wanted..?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me, since I am a self-learner i really apreciate the information and I will work on the code to make it cleaner. Your answer was perfect. Thank you so much.